# HTML autocomplete="new-password": how do I stop autocomplete prompt appearing on preceding input box?

Tags: html, autocomplete

I have a form to register a user with a series of input fields and a password field at the end. I use "autocomplete=new-password" on the password field and this suppresses the autocomplete function. However, when I hover the mouse over the previous input field to the password field, I get a popup listing possible usernames that I can select, and if I select one of them, it fills the input with the username and the following password field with the corresponding password, rather than a tooltip giving the value of the "title" attribute.

```
<input type='text' title='Forename' name='fn'/>
<input type='text' title='Surname'  name='sn'/>
<input type='text' title='Username' name='un'/>
<input type='password' autocomplete='new-password'
       title='Password' name='pw'/>
```

In this case, hovering over the username field "un" shows the password autocomplete popup.

I suppose I could put an invisible input before the password field, but is there a neater way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps the browser is "remembering" past entries that are no longer valid?  Clear your cache to delete these auto-fill entries and start over. Also, you are using duplicate `name` attributes, last one shouldn't be 'fn' I don't think.

Comment: The last one (the password field) should be name='pw'. My fault.

Comment: I don't want a solution which involves the end user having to follow a load of instructions on clearing their cache or whatever; I want the server to serve up HTML that doesn't tempt the browser into unwanted pop-ups. Autocomplete=new-password is not at all all complete as a fix!